# JSLint - ignoring folder when building in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, build, visual-studio-2015, jslint

I want to implement `javascript` code and style checking with `JSLint`.
I installed `JSLint.NET for Visual Studio`.

Now i want to exclude all the javascript files that are included from external libraries like `datatables`, `jquery`, .. also my own minified files need to be excluded.

My project configurations are added in the `JSLintNet.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "output": "Error",
  "ignore": [
    "\\Scripts\\angular-datatables\\plugins\\tabletools\\",
    "\\Scripts\\angular-datatables\\plugins\\fixedcolumns\\angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.js",
    "\\Scripts\\angular-datatables\\plugins\\fixedcolumns\\angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js"
  ],
  "options": {},
  "globalVariables": [],
  "runOnBuild": true
}
```

Whatever path i provide here, is it a folder or a file. The code analysis still keeps running. It is important that i can ignore certain files/ folder for JSLint to be practical.

How can i solve the ignoring of folders and files, perhaps even certain extensions.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. It is still running against the files and folders that I have specified in my JSLintNet.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem and am not certain whether this is the right answer: however, it usually works for me. It seems that JSLint.Net only parses the configuration file on startup; so if you edit JSLintNet.json, quit VisualStudio and restart it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, version 12.0.40629.00 with JSLint.Net 2.2.0

Hope this helps.

Comment: Forgot i had this post but this solved the issue for me some time ago :)

Comment: Yeah this works. However it's insanely annoying to have to close and re-open VS to get the lint rules options to load. Dev really should fix this.